# Is std::this_thread::sleep_for behaviour defined for signal interupt ( or signal handler) in C++11?

Tags: c++, linux

The behavior of `sleep()` in `unistd.h` is well defined in Linux http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html.

Questions:

1. Does the C++11 standard define the behavior of `std::this_thread::sleep_for` for signal interrupt/signal handler? 
   If yes, is the behavior platform dependent? (I hope not)
2. What is the best approach to implement non-interuptable `sleep()` in Linux? Based on my knowledge this can be done by blocking all the signals before calling the `sleep()`.

Answer (score 2):

> Does the C++11 standard define the behavior of std::this_thread::sleep_for for signal interrupt/signal handler?

No.

> is the behavior platform dependent?

Since it's unspecified, it can be.

I tested on linux, and a signal did interrupt the sleep prematurely.

> What is the best approach to implement non-interuptable sleep() in Linux?

A best practice is to not need a non-interruptable `sleep`. `sleep` returns the time left to sleep if it is interrupted, so to prevent premature wakeup, you can simply resume sleep after interruption using a loop:

```
int time = 10;
while(time = sleep(time));
```

Unfortunately, that's not the case with `this_thread::sleep_for` which doesn't return the time left upon interruption.